# program prints only last element in array

Tags: java, arrays, nodes

Why does my program only prints the last element when stored in the array, but when n.getAdjacentNodes().get(p) is printed in the list individually everything works fine. Why doesn't it print the first element?

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoA49.jpg)
ex: see output, why doesn't it print 386.18 instead of 381.42

Also can someone help me to print all the node values in the array.

```
double[][] dist = new double[10][10];
        for (Node n: nodes) {
            System.out.println("");
            for (Node p: n.getAdjacentNodes().keySet()){
                System.out.print("" + n.getName() + " to  " + p.getName() + ": " + String.format("%.2f", n.getAdjacentNodes().get(p)));
                System.out.print("     ");
                //print individually
                System.out.println(n.getAdjacentNodes().get(p));
                
                dist[0][1] = n.getAdjacentNodes().get(p);
               
            }
        }
        //Prints only last element
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(dist).replace("], ", "]\n").replace("[[", "[").replace("]]", "]"));
```

Comment: `dist[0][1]` fills only one field of the array and therefore overwrites the previous values

Comment: Thanks, but if i use a for loop inside the statement : 
for(int i= 0; i < 3; i ++) {
    for(int j= 0; j < 3; j ++) {
                dist[i][j] = n.getAdjacentNodes().get(p);
    }
}

It's still going to overwrite it, any ideas on how can i not overwrite it?

Comment: No need for another for-loop, just define two variables outside of the loop and use `dist[x++][y++]`. I added it as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double[][] dist = new double[10][10];

int x = 0, y = 0;


    for (Node n: nodes) {
        System.out.println("");
        for (Node p: n.getAdjacentNodes().keySet()){
            System.out.print("" + n.getName() + " to  " + p.getName() + ": " + String.format("%.2f", n.getAdjacentNodes().get(p)));
            System.out.print("     ");
            //print individually
            System.out.println(n.getAdjacentNodes().get(p));
            
            dist[x++][y++] = n.getAdjacentNodes().get(p);
           
        }
    }
    //Prints only last element
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(dist).replace("], ", "]\n").replace("[[", "[").replace("]]", "]"));
```